# Sublime Text 3 - can't build reactjs into chrome

Tags: google-chrome, debugging, reactjs, browser, sublimetext3

i created a new build system inside a sublime text3  and saved it as follow :

> {       "cmd": ["‪‪C:\Program
>   Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe","$file"]  }

but when i choose it in the build system and press :control+b" to build it all i get is:

> [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified [cmd:
>   ['\u202a\u202aC:\Program
>   Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe',
>   'C:\Programing\ReduxSimpleStarter-master1\ReduxSimpleStarter-master\src\index.js']]
>   [dir:
>   C:\Programing\ReduxSimpleStarter-master1\ReduxSimpleStarter-master\src]
>   [path: C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA
>   Corporation\PhysX\Common;D:\WampDeveloper\Components\Apache\bin;D:\WampDeveloper\Components\Php;D:\WampDeveloper\Components\Mysql\bin;D:\WampDeveloper\Tools\Perl\perl\bin;C:\Program
>   Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows
>   Live;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program
>   Files\Windows Live\Shared;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL
>   Server\90\Tools\binn\;C:\Program Files\QuickTime\QTSystem\;C:\Program
>   Files\AMD\ATI.ACE\Core-Static;C:\Program Files\ATI
>   Technologies\ATI.ACE\Core-Static;C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Web
>   Platform Installer\;C:\Program Files\DevDesktop\drush;C:\Program
>   Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program
>   Files\cURL\bin;C:\Program Files\Skype\Phone\;C:\Program Files\Windows
>   Kits\10\Windows Performance Toolkit\;C:\Program
>   Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Program Files\CSR\CSR
>   Harmony Wireless Software
>   Stack\;C:\RoR\Rails\RailsInstaller\Git\cmd;C:\RoR\Rails\RailsInstaller\Ruby2.1.0\bin;C:\Program
>   Files\Microsoft VS
>   Code\bin;C:\Users\Daniel.Daniel-PC\AppData\Roaming\npm;%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;]
>   [Finished].

how to i set the build system properly with chrome output ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at your error, you'll see that there are two invisible Unicode characters [`\u202a`](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/202a/index.htm) before the path to Chrome. Open your build system, put your cursor *after* the `C` in `C:\Program Files\...`, press backspace a few times to delete the `C` and the invisible characters, up until you delete the opening double quotes `"`. Now, retype `"C`, save the build system, and rerun it.